# Remove specified string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to remove a string from a div when a user leaves my chatroom, however my it doesn't seem to work. Since most of it work i'l only share the critical code.

```
io.on("user_remove", function (datan) {
document.getElementById("users").list.removeChild(list.childNodes[datan]);
});
```

The list.

```
io.on("user_connected", function (username) {
var html = "";
html += "<li>" + username + "</li>";
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML += html;
});
```

So for example what I recive from "datan" is the username in the list. What I want to happen is for the code above to remove the username datan contains. Think the removeChild function is the flaw here

Comment: provide a minimal reproducible example. DOM elements do not have a "list" property and you don't show where "list" is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to store the username in the data attribute of the `li` and then just remove an `li` with specific data attribute:

```
io.on("user_connected", function (username) {
    var html = "";
    html += "<li data-username='" + username + "'>" + username + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("users").innerHTML += html;
});
```

and then:

```
io.on("user_remove", function (datan) {
    const li = document.querySelector('#users li[data-username="' + datan + '"]');
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
});
```

Comment: smart soulotion would never had thought of that, thanks alot!!